# Exclude <br> tag from regex not to remove from text?

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have code like this

```
string pattern = "<(.|\n)+?>";
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regEx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Reg(pattern);
string result = "";
result = regEx.Replace(htmlText, "");
```

In this "htmlText" will have some html code which also contains break tags. Right now its replacing all the html tags, but I want to leave break tag and replace the rest.
How can  i do it? Anybody have any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this one:

<(?!br|/br).+?>

Comment: Are you sure?.. it is working here.. it matches on all tags I can throw at it except for <br>, </br> and <br/>

Comment: Actually its working, I was testing at the wrong place. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
string html = "<span>test<br><br /></span>";
Regex regex = new Regex("<[^(?!br)>]*>", RegexOptions.Compiled);
string result = regex.Replace(html, string.Empty);
```